# Why undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass in Sinatra/Padrino?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, padrino

I'm following this tutorial http://www.padrinorb.com/guides/blog-tutorial and get a `undefined method email for nil:NilClass` error after assigning a user to all existing posts.

Am I missing something? Possibly the tutorial is out of date with the newest version of Padrino?

Do I need to add some sort of association in models/account.rb ?

**UPDATE & SOLUTION**

Make sure to have the post.rb model in the main folder of the app structure. I had it under app/models.

```
#app/models/post.rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
  validates_presence_of :title
  validates_presence_of :body
end
```

then

```
$ padrino rake ar:migrate:redo
```

Comment: You'll have to post the actual code you're trying. You might have made a mistake while following along the tutorial.

Comment: In fact I did make a mistake. Added solution.

Comment: add your solution as accepted answer http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/